# How can I pickle a dynamically created nested class in python?

Tags: python, class, nested, pickle

I have a nested class:

```
class WidgetType(object):
    
    class FloatType(object):
        pass
    
    class TextType(object):
        pass
```

.. and an object that refers the nested class type (not an instance of it) like this

```
class ObjectToPickle(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.type = WidgetType.TextType
```

Trying to serialize an instance of the ObjectToPickle class results in:

> *PicklingError: Can't pickle <class
> 'setmanager.app.site.widget_data_types.TextType'>*

Is there a way to pickle nested classes in python?

Comment: hehe, is your username a coincidence? :p

Comment: See also the Python pickle documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#the-pickle-protocol

Comment: In Python 3.4 and above, `inst=ObjectToPickle(); pickle.dumps(inst, 4)` works fine.

Answer (score 35):

I know this is a **very** old question, but I have never explicitly seen a satisfactory solution to this question other than the obvious, and most likely correct, answer to re-structure your code.

Unfortunately, it is not always practical to do such a thing, in which case as a very last resort, it **is** possible to pickle instances of classes which are defined inside another class.

The python documentation for the [`__reduce__` function](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html?highlight=__reduce__#object.__reduce__) states that you can return

> A callable object that will be called to create the initial version of the object. The next element of the tuple will provide arguments for this callable.

Therefore, all you need is an object which can return an instance of the appropriate class. This class **must** itself be picklable (hence, must live on the `__main__` level), and could be as simple as:

```
class _NestedClassGetter(object):
    """
    When called with the containing class as the first argument, 
    and the name of the nested class as the second argument,
    returns an instance of the nested class.
    """
    def __call__(self, containing_class, class_name):
        nested_class = getattr(containing_class, class_name)
        # return an instance of a nested_class. Some more intelligence could be
        # applied for class construction if necessary.
        return nested_class()
```

All that is left therefore, is to return the appropriate arguments in a `__reduce__` method on FloatType:

```
class WidgetType(object):

    class FloatType(object):
        def __reduce__(self):
            # return a class which can return this class when called with the 
            # appropriate tuple of arguments
            return (_NestedClassGetter(), (WidgetType, self.__class__.__name__, ))
```

The result is a class which is nested but instances can be pickled (further work is needed to dump/load the `__state__` information, but this is relatively straightforward as per the `__reduce__` documentation).

This same technique (with slight code modifications) can be applied for deeply nested classes.

A fully worked example:

```
import pickle


class ParentClass(object):

    class NestedClass(object):
        def __init__(self, var1):
            self.var1 = var1

        def __reduce__(self):
            state = self.__dict__.copy()
            return (_NestedClassGetter(), 
                    (ParentClass, self.__class__.__name__, ), 
                    state,
                    )


class _NestedClassGetter(object):
    """
    When called with the containing class as the first argument, 
    and the name of the nested class as the second argument,
    returns an instance of the nested class.
    """
    def __call__(self, containing_class, class_name):
        nested_class = getattr(containing_class, class_name)

        # make an instance of a simple object (this one will do), for which we can change the
        # __class__ later on.
        nested_instance = _NestedClassGetter()

        # set the class of the instance, the __init__ will never be called on the class
        # but the original state will be set later on by pickle.
        nested_instance.__class__ = nested_class
        return nested_instance



if __name__ == '__main__':

    orig = ParentClass.NestedClass(var1=['hello', 'world'])

    pickle.dump(orig, open('simple.pickle', 'w'))

    pickled = pickle.load(open('simple.pickle', 'r'))

    print type(pickled)
    print pickled.var1
```

My final note on this is to remember what the other answers have said:

> If you are in a position to do so, consider re-factoring your code to
>   avoid the nested classes in the first place.

Comment: To make it work in Python 3, replace the `w` with `wb` and also `r` with `rb`.

Comment: For the record, this works like a charm for dynamically generated classes (e.g. classes returned by a function), too. Although we should be noted that the classes aren't technically the same in a single Python process in this case, unless we cache and reuse the generated classes based on the parameters.

Comment: Seems like you can just use a function instead of an instance of a completely stateless callable class?

Answer (score 30):

The pickle module is trying to get the TextType class from the module. But since the class is nested it doesn't work. jasonjs's suggestion will work.
Here are the lines in pickle.py responsible for the error message:

```
    try:
        __import__(module)
        mod = sys.modules[module]
        klass = getattr(mod, name)
    except (ImportError, KeyError, AttributeError):
        raise PicklingError(
            "Can't pickle %r: it's not found as %s.%s" %
            (obj, module, name))
```

`klass = getattr(mod, name)` will not work in the nested class case of course. To demonstrate what is going on try to add these lines before pickling the instance:

```
import sys
setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'TextType', WidgetType.TextType)
```

This code adds TextType as an attribute to the module. The pickling should work just fine. I don't advice you to use this hack though.

Comment: A+.  Ran into this, and it seems pickle is just bad to use these days.  Also found your terminal progressbar, which is really neat!

Comment: It's slightly simpler to alias the inner class name at the end of the module with `TextType = WidgetType.TextType`, although it doesn't make it any less hacky and it still screams "remove the inner class".

Answer (score 6):

If you use `dill` instead of `pickle`, it works.

```
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> class WidgetType(object):
...   class FloatType(object):
...     pass
...   class TextType(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class ObjectToPickle(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.type = WidgetType.TextType
... 
>>> x = ObjectToPickle()
>>> 
>>> _x = dill.dumps(x)
>>> x_ = dill.loads(_x)
>>> x_
<__main__.ObjectToPickle object at 0x10b20a250>
>>> x_.type
<class '__main__.TextType'>
```

Get dill here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill

Comment: I did not find information regarding Dill's handling of pickling objects across different namespaces (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696695/store-object-using-python-pickle-and-load-it-into-different-namespace) question)?

Comment: `dill` can pickle the class by reference or by class definition (i.e. it can pickle the class source code).

Answer (score 4):

In Sage ([www.sagemath.org](//www.sagemath.org)), we have many instances of this pickling issue. The way we decided to systematically solve it is to put the *outer* class inside a specific metaclass whose goal is to implement and hide the hack. Note that this automatically propagate through nested classes if there are several level of nesting.

Comment: More elaboration or an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Pickle only works with classes defined in module scope (top level). In this case, it looks like you could define the nested classes in module scope and then set them as properties on WidgetType, assuming there's a reason not to just reference `TextType` and `FloatType` in your code. Or, import the module they're in and use `widget_type.TextType` and `widget_type.FloatType`.

Comment: [..]set them as properties on WidgetType[..]
Doing so yields:
"TypeError: can't pickle property objects"

Answer (score 1):

Nadia's answer is pretty complete - it is practically not something you want to be doing; are you sure you can't use inheritance in `WidgetTypes` instead of nested classes?

The only reason to use nested classes is to encapsulate classes working together closely, your specific example looks like an immediate inheritance candidate to me - there is no benefit in nesting `WidgetType` classes together; put them in a module and inherit from the base `WidgetType` instead.

Comment: I ran into this because I was using `cPickle` with `hashlib.sha1()` to get a hash of a given object instance.  Using a third-party module, [dpkt](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/), I ran into the need to parse ICMP data from a libpcap file and discovered that dpkt uses nested classes in both `ICMP()` and `ICMP6()`.  Changing the code in dpkt's icmp.py works aorund this, but this isn't a practical solution on other systems that I don't control.  Hence, your answer, while sensible, won't apply to all cases because of how other people will write their code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine in newer versions of Python.  I tried it in v3.8 and it was able to pickle and unpickle the nested class.