# ImportError: No module named _gdbm matplotlib pickle

Tags: python, matplotlib

since matplotlib 1.3 matplotlib figures are pickle-able

When I try an example found on stackoverflow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pickle

ax = plt.subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.exp(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
pickle.dump(ax, file('myplot.pickle', 'w'))
```

Source: [Store and reload matplotlib.pyplot object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290370/store-and-reload-matplotlib-pyplot-object)

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Work/Programming/Experimental/picklematplotlib/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    pickle.dump(ax, file)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 116, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 105, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 76, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\dbm\gnu.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: No module named _gdbm
```

I am using matplotlib-1.3.1.win-amd64.py3.2.exe version of matplotlib
together with python3.2 on an 64bit windows machine

according to: http://docs.python.org/2/library/gdbm.html gdbm is named dbm.gnu in python3.
so is it a software bug in matplotlib or what could I do to make it working.

surprisingly the .pickle file is created and useable.
this means, the program crashes directly after writing the .pickle file

Comment: no, i considered pickle of matplotlibs as not ready to use in matplotlib 1.3. maybe the situation has changed with mpl 1.4

Comment: Update `six` package separately from other packages. If you are still having a problem, file a bug report to `six` with an example that does not required matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Update to matplotlib version 1.3.1 and the script you posted does not give any error (using Python 2.7.6)