# How to make gif images from a set of images in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, jpeg, gif

How to make '.gif' image from a set of '.jpg' images (say: I1.jpg, I2.jpg,..., I10.jpg) in matlab?

Comment: you mean how to use imwrite with the .gif extension?

Comment: Yes, actually I went through matlab tutorial and tried to change that example to my case but could not as that example used plotting of a function but in my case, it is jpg images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok here is a simple example. I got an image with a unicorn on it and remove 2 part to create 3 different images, just for the sake of creating an animated gif. Here is what it looks like:

```
clear
clc

%// Image source: http:\\giantbomb.com
A = rgb2gray(imread('Unicorn1.jpg'));
B = rgb2gray(imread('Unicorn2.jpg'));
C = rgb2gray(imread('Unicorn3.jpg'));

ImageCell = {A;B;C};

figure;
subplot(131)
imshow(A)

subplot(132)
imshow(B)

subplot(133)
imshow(C)

%// Just to show what the images look like (I removed spots to make sure there was an animation created):
```

[image]

```
%// Create file name.
FileName = 'UnicornAnimation.gif';

for k = 1:numel(ImageCell)

    if k ==1

%// For 1st image, start the 'LoopCount'.
        imwrite(ImageCell{k},FileName,'gif','LoopCount',Inf,'DelayTime',1);
    else
        imwrite(ImageCell{k},FileName,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',1);
    end

end
```

As you see, its not that different from the example on the Mathworks website. Here my images are in a cell array but yours might be in a regular array or something else.That should work fine; when I open 'UnicornAnimation.gif' it is indeed a nice animation!

Hope that helps!

Comment: How about RGB images with transparency?