# Pickling Matplotlib plot raising PicklingError: Can't pickle 'RendererAgg' object

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle, figure, dill

I have a program that creates plots - sometimes line plots, sometimes NonUniformImages - using matplotlib. I'd like to be able to pickle the plots to reopen them at a later time without going through the whole creation process again. For whatever reason, it keeps throwing a `PicklingError: Can't pickle 'RendererAgg' object`. I've tried using both `import dill as pickle` and `import pickle`, as well as all 4 different pickling options but no change.

The axes are defined here:

```
class Imaging:
    def function:
        ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
        ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
```

And set here: (Imaging.figureProperties is a list and is meant to hold multiple `[ax1,ax2]` objects. Also in the same function as where `ax1` and `ax2` are defined.)

```
Imaging.figureProperties.append([ax1,ax2])
```

Finally, data is pickled here (`i` is chosen by the user, but it will be within the list):

```
class2:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(Imaging.figureProperties[i-1],f)
```

I have no problem running the sample code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290370/store-and-reload-matplotlib-pyplot-object) (with some slight changes such as opening in `'wb'` instead of just `'w'`), as long as I use `import dill as pickle`. If I use the standard `import pickle` it throws the same `PicklingError`. What is going on here?

Comment: What version of mpl?  I think we cleaned up a bunch of these things recently.

Comment: @tcaswell, I was using 1.4.0. Just updated to 1.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the `dill` author.  If you edit your question to provide code that can be tested, I could better test your code.   I think it might be that you just have typos in your code above -- it should be `def function(self):`.  Also what is `class2:`?  I'll just cut to the chase and serialize the thing you are trying to serialize.  Your code as posted doesn't really make sense.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> 
>>> class Imaging:
...   def function(self):
...     ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
...     ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
... 
>>> Imaging.figureProperties = []
>>> 
>>> import dill
>>>                                     
>>> ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
>>> ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
>>> Imaging.figureProperties.append([ax1, ax2])
>>> fp = dill.loads(dill.dumps(Imaging.figureProperties[0]))
>>> fp   
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x113085320>, <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x113471eb8>]
```

The class you are using is pretty pointless as you are using it, however the code you are asking to serialize does serialize.

Comment: I just meant to show the general structure as the code I have is rather messy, but I realize now that I should have just uploaded it all in the first place. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Matplotlib to 1.4.2 solved the problems.