# Store plotted data for later use

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I do much (practically all) of my data analysis in Jupyter/iPython-notebooks. For convenience, I obviously also plot my data in those notebooks using `matplotlib`/`pyplot`.
Some of those plots I need to recreate externally later on, for example to use them in `latex`. For this I save the corresponding data as textfiles to the harddrive. Right now, I manually create a numpy-array by stacking all the data needed for the plot, and save this using `numpy.savetxt`.

What I would like to have is a way to save *all* data needed for a specific plot written to the same file in an (semi)automatic way, but I am at a loss if it comes to the smart way of doing so.

Thus I have two questions:

- Is it possible (and save to do) to create something like a plot-memory object, that stores all data plotted per figure, and has a method similar to `Memoryobject.save_plot_to_file(figname)`? This object would need to know which figure I am working on, so I would need to create a layer above matplotlib, or get this information from the matplotlib objects
- Is there a simpler way? The python universe is huge, and I do not know half of it. Maybe something like this already exists?

**Edit**: Clarification: I do *not* want to save the figure object. What I want to do is something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.plot(x1, y1)
fig.plot(x2, y2 + y3)

# and at a later point
arrays = get_data_from_plot(fig)
data = process(arrays)
np.savetxt('textfile', data)
```

Comment: Never tried it myself, but maybe pickling the figure object would work???

Comment: @Dux To extract data from the plot, maybe you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938449/how-to-extract-data-from-matplotlib-plot).

Answer (score 0):

You could pickle the object (using the `cPickle` module).  See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290370/store-and-reload-matplotlib-pyplot-object).

Comment: Sorry, it seems my question was misleading. I updated it. Bottom line, I only want the data of the plot during runtime, NOT save the figure object

Comment: You can use `cPickle` for saving data.  I used `cPickle` within Jupyter notebooks to save data and reload it at a later time.  You can save a variable within the pickled object to tell you which plotting function you used if that's what you're after.

Comment: I know that. But I *do* need the data saved to the disk in text format, e.g. csv.