# python matplotlib save graph as data file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a python script that zooms in and out of matplotlib graphs along the horizontal axis. My plot is a set of horizontal bar graphs.

I also want to make that able to take any generic matplotlib graph.

I do not want to just load an image and zoom into that, I want to zoom into the graph along the horizontal axis. (I know how to do this)

Is there some way I can save and load a created graph as a data file or is there an object I can save and load later?

(typically, I would be creating my graph and then displaying it with the matplotlib plt.show, but the graph creation takes time and I do not want to recreate the graph every time I want to display it)

Comment: Do you want to save the graph, or the underlying data?

Comment: @DavidZ The underlying data, the array or whatever that holds the graph data.

Comment: Maybe you can use pickle to save your object and then load it again later? https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` and others return the underlying data you can `pickle` and save for later use.

Comment: You can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290370/store-and-reload-matplotlib-pyplot-object

Comment: Check the example code I answered. I believe it works from Python 2.7 onwards. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Try to use `open` function instead of `file` as in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) package for saving your axes and then load it back.

Save your plot into a `pickle` file:

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.plot([1,2,5,10])
pickle.dump(ax, open("plot.pickle", "wb"))
```

And then load it back:

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
ax = pickle.load(open("plot.pickle", "rb"))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am using fig,(graph,label_texts)=plt.subplots(2,1,gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[4.5, 1]}) to generate my plots.

and then

I'm trying pickle.dump(fig,file(file_name.split('.')[0]+'_graph.pickle'‌​,'w')) which gives me: <class 'pickle.PicklingError'> Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x0CB02FB0>: it's not found as generate_graph.<lambda> Which seems to be an issue with how I generate my image. Any thoughts? @Cedric

Comment: Try `pickle.dump(fig, open("plot.pickle", "wb"))` . I think you should use `open` instead of `file`

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I suppose it's a pickle issue and not the open thing.

Comment: Did you try out "wb" instead of "w"?

Comment: I did. The problem was pickling thing with functions in them, adding the dill library as below was the solution

Answer (score 3):

@Cedric's Answer.

Additionally, if you get the pickle error for pickling functions, add the 'dill' library to your pickling script. You just need to import it at the start, it will do the rest.