# Saving plot settings to a file

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to save the settings of the current figure or subplot to a file? I don't mean general configuration such as font size.  I would like to save specific things such as the current x-axis limits, scale, or regions of interest to a file and restore that to a plot at a later time.  Is there a simple way to do this with matplotlib (or another library based off of matplotlib)?

Comment: Have you looked into [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)? I'm not sure if `matplotlib` objects are supported but it might be of interest to you.

Comment: @Idlehands, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290370/store-and-reload-matplotlib-pyplot-object suggests that might be a workable approach.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you asking how to save a figure including all axes limits etc or are you asking how to save the setting to latter apply them to a different figure?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, how to save the settings and apply them later to a different figure.  The pickle approach would require copying over all of the settings between the two figures, but it may be workable.