# Store the plot object in dict and plt.show later

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn for lineplot. I want to store all the plot objects in dict and show (display) the plot later accoding to the dict key.

```
lookup = df_to_plot['lookup'].unique()
figures = {}
for key in lookup:
      figures[key] = plt.figure()
      datadf = df_to_plot[df_to_plot['lookup'] == key]
      sns.lineplot(data=datadf, x ='year', y='value', hue='tech_low')
```

Later I want to show the plots like:

```
key = 'xyz'
plt = figures[key]
plt.show()
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: [Store and reload matplotlib.pyplot object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7290370/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky it uses the internal `_pylab_helpers` module: the following example silently creates 3 Figures, stores them in the dict and then brings up the second Figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers

figures = {}
for i in range(3):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.suptitle(f"Figure {i}")
    figures[f"Fig{i}"] = fig
    plt.close()


def show_fig(fig):
    _pylab_helpers.Gcf.set_active(fig.canvas.manager)
    plt.show()


show_fig(figures["Fig1"])
```