# How to acquire apache-beam .tar.gz file?

Tags: sdk, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Apache-beam has been frustrating to manage with the correct google-cloud libraries for me to use with Dataflow.

I discovered for what I'm doing I need apache-beam=2.3.0 rather than 2.4.0 (2.4.0 gives a pickling error that I cannot resolve refer to [Dataflow Error: 'Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611890/dataflow-error-clients-have-non-trivial-state-that-is-local-and-unpickleable))

I need DataflowRunner to use apache-beam=2.3.0 as well so following this persons instructions [Custom Apache Beam Python version in Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348986/custom-apache-beam-python-version-in-dataflow) **I just need the actual tar.gz file**  I thought I had installed it via pip with a pip install apache-beam=2.3.0 so if I look in my system I can't find any tar.gz. When I go to the apache website to download the source code the link is broken.

**Where can I find a tar.gz for apache-beam-2.3.0?**

Comment: https://github.com/apache/beam/releases

Comment: thanks! I am just getting the ropes of this stuff

Comment: @greeness could you move your comment to an answer? It might prove useful for the community in the future

Comment: Sure, moved it to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The latest and all history releases of apache-beam packages can be found on github - [github.com/apache/beam/releases](https://github.com/apache/beam/releases).