# Pickling an instance of a dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Is there a possibility to pickle/dill `an_instance` developed as follows?

```py
import dill
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dataclasses import make_dataclass, field

fields = [('float_val', float, field(default=np.nan)),
          ('df', pd.DataFrame, field(default_factory=pd.DataFrame)),
          ('int_val', int, field(default_factory=int)),
          ('time_val', datetime, field(default=datetime.now(timezone.utc)))]

Aclass = make_dataclass('Aclass', fields)

an_instance=Aclass()

dill.dump(an_instance, open('test.pkl', 'wb'))
```

The dump gives `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'types.Aclass'>: it's not found as types.Aclass`

Comment: What does the `dill` documentation say are the requirements of an object to be pickled? Have you searched with the error message?

Comment: Did you see this one? [How can I pickle a dynamically created nested class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947904/how-can-i-pickle-a-dynamically-created-nested-class-in-python) It is a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Thx @Tom Myddeltyn for Issue35510 bug tracker. `dill.dump` and `dill.load` works by setting the name using `Aclass.__module__ = __name__`.

Full code is as follows:

```
fields = [('float_val', float, field(default=np.nan)),
          ('df', pd.DataFrame, field(default_factory=pd.DataFrame)),
          ('int_val', int, field(default_factory=int)),
          ('time_val', datetime, field(default=datetime.now(timezone.utc)))]

Aclass = make_dataclass('Aclass', fields)
Aclass.__module__ = __name__ # provide name for pickling the class

an_instance=Aclass()

dill.dump(an_instance, open('test.pkl', 'wb'))
dill.load(open('test.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is unsupported in `pickle` which probably means `dill` as well.
[Python bug tracker Issue35510 :pickling derived dataclasses](https://bugs.python.org/issue35510)

> Dataclasses are pickled by name, as well as other classes. Pickling classes which can not be accessed by name is not supported. - Serhiy Storchaka (2018-12-16)

Also see here for more details with `dill`.
[github dill issue tracker](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/56)

Comment: I believe your answer gets invalidated by the other answer that provides a solution.